# Setting selection background in ListCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm trying to set a custom background for selected items in wxPython 2.8. I cannot figure out how to do so. I've tried SetItemBackground with no luck.

Comment: Similar/ related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767484/is-it-possible-to-change-the-colour-of-the-focus-selector-of-a-listctrl, as pointed out by @vz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected items in `wxListCtrl`, `wxListBox` and so on always use the system background selection colour, it can't be changed.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Is there any work around for it?