# Is it possible to change the colour of the "focus selector" of a ListCtrl?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets, wxperl

In Mozilla Thunderbird mail you can assing items in a list a colour. The "focus selector" usually has the "cursor colour" that is defined by the window theme on your OS. Now, when you select a coloured item in Thunderbird, the focus cursor changes colour accordingly. That is to indicate that this item has a colour. Otherwise the user could only see that this particular item has a colour by moving away the "focus selector".

Now, is this possible in WxWindows, a WxListCtrl? Apart from changing the font-colour (SetForegroundColour) and the item's background (SetbackgroundColour, which is usually white)?

[image: "Focus selector" set on the first entry in a two item list ListCtrl]

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate but very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624070/setting-selection-background-in-listctrl/22635854#22635854 and the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wxPython toolkit wraps the native widget of the OS as much as possible. I don't believe any native widgets support custom colors for the "cursor color". You might want to take a look at the UltimateListCtrl. I'm not sure if that has this feature out of the box, but it is a pure Python list control and I'm sure you could patch it much more easily to add that functionality.